# How to test an independent class in angular unit test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have an independent class need to test in angular. I wonder how I could dependency inject a mock service for it.

I try to use TestBed to dependency inject the service. But it doesn't work.

```js
// user-setting.ts, class I want to test
constructor(private config: UserSettingDefault, private userSettingsService: UserSettingsService) { }

// user-setting.spec.ts, I try to use TestBed to inject, but failed
class UserSettingsServiceMock {

}

fdescribe('UserSetting', () => {
  let userSettingsService: UserSettingsServiceMock

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: UserSettingsService, useClass: UserSettingsServiceMock },
      ],
    });

    userSettingsService = TestBed.get(UserSettingsService);
  });

  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const config = { app: 'user', type: 'search', id: 'embeded-link' };
    const userSetting = new UserSetting(config, userSettingsService);
    expect(userSetting).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I expect I could create a new instance for UserSetting. But throw some error:

```
ERROR in src/app/core/user/user-settings/user-setting.spec.ts(25,49): error TS2345: Argument of type 'UserSettingsServiceMock' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserSettingsService'.
  Property 'language' is missing in type 'UserSettingsServiceMock'.
```

Comment: perhaps you should create a stackblitz and we should be able to help to resolve the issue

Comment: userSettingsService is a complex service. Do you know how could I test user-setting.ts without inject userSettingsService?

Comment: Could you please share a bit more information on the user-setting.ts? What do you mean by independent? You are not using it inside angular's dependency injection?

Comment: welll... try to add `language: string` or whatever type you have for language to your mock... you can make the mock and the service use the same interface.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you are mocking the service in your component, then you must provide the dummy skeleton of that service (i.e. you need to write mock methods and variables in that mock injected dependency which all are the component is using).
You are getting error, because, you must be using `userSettingsService.language` in your component. So, you need to mock this value as well.

```
class UserSettingsServiceMock {
language = {};
}
```